# Notepad++ automatically completing \begin{env} \end{env}

Tags: editors

Is there a way to configure Notepad++ to do the following:

- After I type `\begin{env}` (and perhaps some shortcut keys), it automatically closes the environment with `\end{env}` and moves the cursor to a line between the opening and closure of the environment. Here `env` is any environment name.

I know this can be done in Emacs, as is shown in [Get emacs to automatically insert \end{} commands after a \begin{} command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154287/get-emacs-to-automatically-insert-end-commands-after-a-begin-command). I'm wondering if there's a Notepad++ equivalent.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use a proper editor with support for TeX?

Comment: @cfr: I've experimented with quite a few actually: TeXWorks (forgot why I didn't like it, it was a long time ago); LyX (doesn't handle `.tex` document directly); BaKoMa TeX (incompatible with XeLaTeX and some functionalities of PGF); Emacs (steep learning curve, never found time to really learn it). Also, I like Notepad++ as a text editor, simple and light. What editor would you recommend using? I know there's a big list on meta... Sometimes too many choices aren't always good.

Comment: I'm the wrong person to ask because I have no idea what Notepad++ is like so I can't suggest anything which might go down well. I currently use Kile which I like but it would hardly be considered 'light'. I'm not sure I would use it if I weren't using KDE anyway. (Since I'm using KDE, Kile sits nicely on top but the dependencies would be annoyingly heavy otherwise. And I doubt it is the best choice on Windows.)

Comment: @KevinC, I really recommend TeXstudio. It is wonderful!

Comment: @KevinC Uwe Ziegenhagen uses AutoHotkey for such things, see: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2763

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from @Fuzzy's answer, I believe that it is *Snippet Parameters* that will help here, as detailed in https://github.com/erinata/FingerText/wiki/Snippet-parameters

Starting from notepad++, with the `Fingertext` plugin installed (details in [Fuzzy's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213954/6621)), go to:

```
Plugins-> Fingertext-> Toggle On/off SnippetDock-> Open Snippet Editor
```

Now enter, for example, `env` as `triggertext`, keep `3` as `GLOBAL` and enter the following into the `Snippet Content`

```
\begin{$[![envname]!]}
    $[![(environment body)]!]
\end{$[![envname]!]}$[![after environment]!][>END<]
```

[image: screenshot]

This should now mean that when you type, for example

```
 env(myenvironment)<TAB>
```

you receive

```
\begin{myenvironment}
    (environment body)
\end{myenvironment}$[![after environment]!]
```

with the cursor highlighting `(environment body)`. You can then `TAB` to after the environment when you're done.

There is *a lot* more to explore on the Wiki, https://github.com/erinata/FingerText/wiki.

Comment: Perhaps we could start a github repo of useful snippets? I use notepad++ a lot at work, so would be interested in sharing/contributing to something that would make TeXing easier

Comment: @HerrK. awesome :) let me know if you'd like to collaborate on a snippets repo, I hope to build some soon

Answer (score 3):

There are two different ways to implement this. One using only blank Notepad++, and one with additional AddOn

1. With AddOn (very cool!!!)

Open Plugins->PluginManager in Notepad++.
Install the Addon "FingerText"
Now in the FingerText AddOn click "Open Snippet Editor" and define a "Trigger Text" (poorly \ is not usable. Therefore simply use "begin" for instance)
Under "Snippet Content" add your Code, including an additional command to force the Cursor to end up between opening and closure.
Should look like this:

\begin{env}
$[0[]0]
\end{env}[>END<]

Save Snippet and open a Tex-File.
Insert the code by clicking on the FingerText-SnippetDock.
Or if you now type begin and press Tab-Key, the Code will be autocompleted and the cursor ends up in the desired Position ;-)

---

2. Without AddOn (Not so handy, because Cursor stops at the end of the code)

Open the folder /Plugins/APIs of you Notepad++ installation directory and open the file
"tex.xml" which contains all TeX-Autocomplete Informations.
Now simply add you desired autocomplete command:

It should look like this:

```
<KeyWord name="begin{env}\end{env}" />
```

Now activate Autocompletion in Notepad++ (Settings->Preferences->Autocompletion)

If you now type \begi... in you document Notepad++ will autocomplete the Code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! With the FingerText Add-on, I'm able to get automatic insertion of *a particular* environment called `env`. However, is there a way to get automatic insertion of *any* environment? That is, is it possible to configure FingerText so that `env` becomes an argument in the shortcut, and thus whenever I type the sequence `begin{<env>}` + Tab, where `<env>` is any legitimate environment name, the whole environment gets automatically inserted?